# How can I initialize a empty file without giving it a path in flutter after null safety is enabled

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I was working on a project for which I require the user to select a file from his/her device. The way I did it before flutter updated to enable null safety was that I would initialize an empty file and after the user picks the file the empty file gains the path of the selected file. This was the code to do it -

```
File myfile;
Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    FilePickerResult? result =
        await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.image);
    if (result != null) {
      PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
 setState(() {
        myFile = File(file.path.toString());  
      });
```

But after I updated flutter to 2.5.2 it started giving an error , 'Non-nullable instance field 'myFile' must be initialized.'. My IDE suggests adding a late modifier before initializing the file, but after picking the file the app crashes due to that. Is there any way around this?
Please help

Comment: File myfile = File('');

Comment: Not everything has to be non-nullable.  You're free to make variables nullable when it makes sense for them to be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your variable *can be* null, then just make it nullable:

```
File? myfile;
```

Null-Safety is a great feature to let you see faster and more effective when something *can* or *cannot* be null. But some variables *can* be null. That's totally fine. All null safety requires is that you declare them as such using the question mark as seen above.